# onLayout doesn't get fired if the View component is wrapped in TouchableNativeFeedback

Tags: android, react-native

I was expecting **Hey** to be printed as an output for the below given code snippet:

```
<TouchableNativeFeedback>        
  <View onLayout={ () => console.log( 'hey' ) }>
    <Text>Hey</Text>
  </View>
<TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

But, `onLayout` never gets fired. I tried this on Android. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I need to retrieve the width of the `View`.

[React Native](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.44/): 0.44

Comment: Any luck solving this issue I am having the same one?